# Array Values Not Passing

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables, collectionview, completionhandler

So this may seem elementary, but I am genuinely confused because this works as expected on another view.

Basically, I am trying to pass an array to my collectionview, but I found the array was not passing globally, making my collection view empty. It was passing globally in another class I created. I print the variable to see if they were printing and they were printing within the retrieveData method but is coming up as an empty array ([]) when I call self.retrieveData.

```
var name = [String]()
var iD = [String]()
var avi = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    noUsersLbl.isHidden = true
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    self.retrieveData { (response) in


//prints [] here
        if(self.name == []){
            self.noUsersLbl.isHidden = false
            self.collectionView.isHidden = true 
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }      
}

public func retrieveData(completion: @escaping(String) -> ()) {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let dbBus = Firestore.firestore().collection("business").whereField("zip", isEqualTo: "63135")
    
    
    dbBus.getDocuments { (document, error) in
        if error == nil {
            guard let doc = document else { return }
            for document in doc.documents{
                let data = document.data()
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                self.name.append(name)
                let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                self.id.append(id)
                let avi = data["avi"] as? String ?? ""
                self.avi.append(avi)
// prints list here
                }
                completion("complete")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify where did you try to print you data (for example "name" array) and in which place of code it's empty and in which it's not.

Comment: @MikhailVasilev I printed in retrieveData and got [], self.retrieveData and got a list. I clarified exactly where in the code.

Comment: What is `self.result`? why do you expect it to be changed? it's not changed in `retrieveData`...

Comment: It is changed in retrieveData. It's being printed but not passing globally. self.result could be looked at as name[], id[] or avi[]. changed variable names for demo purposes. I used the same code in a different class that worked so I expected it to work the same. changed the code.

Comment: And you are printing "name" array not "result", right? So, inside getDocuments your name "array" is not empty, and inside "retrieveData" completion block it's empty?

Comment: That's correct @MikhailVasilev